# How do I write the following OR?

Tags: php, or-operator

This little piece of code always returns "Equal". I must have something wrong syntax wise but I really can't find what. It's driving me crazy.

```
<?php

    $var = "1";

    if($var == "2" or "3") {
        echo "Equal";
    } else {
        echo "Different";
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: `if($var == "2" or "3")` you need to add an additional condition `if($var == "2" || $var == "3")` `||` (OR). or check if it's in an array.

Comment: This is basic conditional checking http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "3" is always true since it is non zero. You need to check against the variable again in the second condition.

```
if($var == "2" OR $var == "3") {
    echo "Equal";
} else {
    echo "Different";
}
```

Also, you should use || instead of OR due to unexpected results. Check out the operator precedence.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($var == "2" || $var ==  "3")
```

Comment: *"Try"* doesn't give them much of an explanation.